# What is the function pointer of the print builtin function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, pointers, monkeypatching

How can we get the function pointer of the builtin print function in python.

It seems to behave differently than the other builtin functions:

```
>>> a = print
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>>> dir(print)
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

>>>> m = map
OK

>>>> dir(map)
['__call__', '__class__', [...] '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
```

Comment: In 2.x, `print` *isn't a function*.

Comment: For extra context, see [PEP 3105](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't do this because print is a keyword in Python 2.7, so it would be along the lines of saying something like:

```
>>> a = if
```

Doesn't make too much sense.

You have two options.

1. Use python 3
2. Import the python equivalent: `from __future__ import print_function`

Answer (score 3):

In Python 2.7 , `print` is a statement not a function (whereas `map` is a built-in function).

If you want the `print` function in Python 2.x , you would need to do -

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Please note, this would make `print` function for the rest of your program.